# parallel.invoke cancellation token

Tags: .net-4.0, parallel-processing, task-parallel-library, cancellation-token

When using Parallel.Invoke, you're able to pass in ParallelOptions which includes a cancelationToken. Is it possible to use that token in the invocations to determine if exiting should occur? Should a reference to the CancellationTokenSource be used from within the actions?

```
CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
ParallelOptions po = new ParallelOptions();
po.CancellationToken = cts.Token;

Parallel.Invoke(po,
        new Action(() => { if (cts.IsCancellationRequested) return; Console.WriteLine("Invoked Method 1"); }),
        new Action(() => { if (cts.IsCancellationRequested) return; Console.WriteLine("Invoked Method 2"); }),
        new Action(() => { if (cts.IsCancellationRequested) return; Console.WriteLine("Invoked Method 3"); cts.Cancel(); }),
        new Action(() => { if (cts.IsCancellationRequested) return; Console.WriteLine("Invoked Method 4"); }),
        new Action(() => { if (cts.IsCancellationRequested) return; Console.WriteLine("Invoked Method 5"); })
    );
```

Update: The cancellation was happening too late. I was doing it outside of the invoked methods.

Note: If the cancellation happens soon enough, the Parallel.Invoke will throw, but otherwise the inoked methods will exit without fail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. For example:

```
CancellationToken ct = tokenSource.Token;

ParallelOptions po = new ParallelOptions { CancellationToken = ct; };

Parallel.Invoke(po
    () => { Console.WriteLine(ct.IsCancellationRequested); },
    // etc
);
```

In particular, you could pass the cancellation token into other methods which may propagate it to asynchronous tasks.

Comment: John, I was doing that (though my posted example doesnt show it) but all methods would continue execution until completion.

Comment: @DustinDavis: You'd need to show how you actually checked for cancellation. A complete example - along with what happens - would make it easier to diagnose the problem.

Comment: I figured it out. The cancellation was happening too late.

Answer (score 2):

There is a fairly good example on msdn.

it seems you can both query the status and use the cancellationToken to signal the scheduler.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997364.aspx